# Threepenny Gui - Inserting Javascript files Into HTML header, and failed <script> implementation

Tags: user-interface, haskell, threepenny-gui

I am using Threepenny GUI to implement a front end to a graphical database. To save time, I wish to use already-built Javascript JQuery-oriented code files in the GUI display page. I am using FireFox browser on Mac for its' html code inspection abilities.

A problem or two appeared when trying to include a canvas-related element.

There is no function already written to include Javascript source into the displayed HTML page header.

I addressed this by reading some of the Threepenny source to determine how to craft my own routine. Borrowing the function definition for addStyleSheet as a model, the code was copied into the source to test it:

```
UI.addStyleSheet rootWindow "gui_fmiq.css"
-- the following code does the above and works in this context --
el <- mkElement "link"
    # set (attr "rel" ) "stylesheet"
    # set (attr "type") "text/css"
    # set (attr "href") ("/static/css/gui_fmiq.css")
getHead rootWindow #+ [element el]
```

A copy of the local CSS file was installed in the header according to Firefox's HTML inspector, so this problem was solved.

However, putting in a jquery.js file in a similar way caused the HTML display to go totally-white-page-display wonky. I don't know if this is an interaction with Threepenny's version of jquery.js or not. Nonetheless JQuery is required by the javascript code.

The main problem:

Using a similar style of code, I crafted a function sequence to construct an HTML script primitive to place a javascript source into the HTML header:

```
inc_sketchScript <- mkElement "script"
    # set (attr "src") "/static/sketch.js"
getHead rootWindow
    #+ [
        element inc_sketchScript
       ]
```

The included javascript file doesn't show in the HTML inspector of Firefox, but the Threepenny launch terminal shows it in a GET 200 response in the web server.

Using very similar code in a later canvas definition to exploit the included javascript:

```
    canvas <- UI.canvas
    # set UI.height canvasHeight
    # set UI.width  canvasWidth
    # set style [("border", "solid black 1px"), ("background", "#eee")]
    # set UI.id_ "simple_sketch"
    #+ [
        mkElement "script"
            # set (attr "type") "text/javascript"
            # set text "$(function() {$('simple_sketch').sketch(); });"
       ]
```

The expected script HTML code fails to appear at all in the Firefox HTML inspector. The canvas itself shows onscreen, but does nothing.

This question is for the creator of Threepenny, Heinrich Apfelmus.

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: Be sure to create an issue at https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/threepenny-gui/issues/new as well.

Comment: I haven't had time to check yet, unfortunately, but does it help to add the <script> element to the *body* instead of to the head? This seems to be standard procedure nowadays for including scripts after the page has loaded.

Comment: Yes, I realised that after examining a number of script examples. The only question now is how to send graphical contents of the canvas when a button is pressed. I failed at calling the javascript directly - too many type conflicts with the Threepenny library. I would like to send a PNG or JPG bytestream from the html page to Haskell for further processing, instead of uisng the data to open a window in the browser (which is dead standard practise).